# Android - Un-erasable application 5

Tags: android, android-emulator

I used the mobile programming (Android) and when I run the application .. it stops and I see the message

```
([2013-06-21 20:01:23 - CurrencyConverter] Failed to install CurrencyConverter.apk on device 'emulator-5554!)
```

why?

Comment: kill adb, close avd, restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

after one failure don't close the avd. Run the application again. If other things are okay then it should run. If still the problem exists. From avd manager delete the avd and create a new one and try.